# jQuery $.post on checkbox change not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The code was working, and for some reason I don't know, it stopped working.

jQuery (inside document.ready):

```
$('#hideFriendsPublicView').on('click', function() {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                alert($('#hideFriendsPublicView').length);
                $.post("ajax.php", { checked: 1, owner_id:<?php echo $profileData[0]['id']; ?>}); //owner_id as an int, as the id in mysql is of type int too.
            } else {
                alert($('#hideFriendsPublicView').length);
                $.post("ajax.php", { checked: 0, owner_id:<?php echo $profileData[0]['id']; ?>});
            }
});
```

HTML:

```
if ( $profileData[0]['showFriends'] ) {
   echo '<label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="hideFriendsPublicView"> Hide my friends from public view.</label>';
} else {
   echo '<label><input type="checkbox" id="hideFriendsPublicView"> Hide my friends from public view.</label>';
}
```

PHP:

```
if ( isset($_POST['checked']) ) {
    $query = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET showFriends = :newState WHERE id = :id");
    $query->execute(array(
        ':newState' => $_POST['checked'],
        ':id' => $_POST['owner_id']
    ));
}
```

It seems like with this same exact code, the ajax.php file was getting fired up when clicking the check box, and MySQL was also getting updated.

Now, the PHP file doesn't get fired up when clicking (I also tried on('change').

Edit: both of the `alert($('#hideFriendsPublicView').length)` alerts are getting fired when checking/unchecking the checkbox and return 1.

Edit: I also tried using only strings initially in the jQuery, IE:

```
    $('#hideFriendsPublicView').on('click', function() {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert($('#hideFriendsPublicView').length);
            $.post("ajax.php", { checked: "checked", owner_id:"<?php echo $profileData[0]['id']; ?>"});
        } else {
            alert($('#hideFriendsPublicView').length);
            $.post("ajax.php", { checked: "unchecked", owner_id:"<?php echo $profileData[0]['id']; ?>"});
        }
    });
```

And the PHP to cast ints on these strings (the type of the 2 columns is int):

```
if ( isset($_POST['checked']) ) {
    if ( $_POST['checked'] == "checked" ) {
        $_POST['checked'] = 1;
    } else {
        $_POST['checked'] = 0;
    }
    $query = $conn->prepare("UPDATE tusers SET profile_showFriends = :newState WHERE id = :id");
    $query->execute(array(
        ':newState' => $_POST['checked'],
        ':id' => (int) $_POST['owner_id']
    ));
}
```

But that also fails.

Comment: do you see any errors in console...?

Comment: before, i was seeing ajax.php getting fired in the console, but not anymore, and no errors as well.

Comment: can you try `$('#hideFriendsPublicView').length` in the browser console.. also `alert($('#hideFriendsPublicView').length)` before the event is added

Comment: Try wrapping `<?php echo $profileData[0]['id']; ?>` with quotation marks.

Comment: one question... is the html loaded dynamically?

Comment: @ArunPJohny - both the alerts return 1. The HTML is loaded dynamically, but I also tried statically.

Comment: @undefined -- I tried it, the $.post event still didn't fire up. (When doing so I also casted (int) on the $_POST['owner_id'] since the id in mysql is int)

Comment: Check in your browser if AJAX request is being sent (e.g. in Chrome you can do it by launching dev tools - F12 - and opening Network tab). If it is being sent, check what POST data is included in the request.

Comment: checked=1&owner_id=23 are being sent to PHP indeed

Comment: omfg... I had changed the mysql column to profile_hideFriends and I was still using profile_showFriends... I'm going to play in the traffic now. fuuuu. Thanks everybody anyway.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localised.

Answer (score 0):

Think the problem may cause by your owner_id is a `string`

I not sure your user id is string or integer. if it string you should warp it up with `"`. if you dont javascript will think is a `variable`

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                alert("bla");
                $.post("ajax.php", { checked: 1, owner_id:"<?php echo $profileData[0]['id']; ?>" });
            } else {
                alert("bla");
                $.post("ajax.php", { checked: 0, owner_id:"<?php echo $profileData[0]['id']; ?>" });
            }
```

Comment: Hi, please check my edits with updates. I am using strings in jQuery for both the checked and owner_id, and then use them as int in the PHP.